# некорректная обработка парсера XML при встрече с символом &amp;

Tags: xml

есть строка в xml документе :

```
<bMS>sss1&amp;sss2</bMS>
```

на выходе имею три разные строки :

```
sss1
&amp
sss2
```

а хотелось бы одну такого вида :

```
sss1 & sss2
```

почему так получается?

Comment: чем парсите то?

Comment: xml_set_default_handler($xml_parser,"trt_champ"); на входе "trt_champ" уже три строки (в php практически полный профан, код не мой, но работать надо..)

Comment: и что в вашем `trt_champ()` происходит?

Comment: я к тому что, приведите конкретный пример кода который вызывает подобное поведение, чтобы его можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: Парсите правильно. В php как минимум я встечал три парсера. Приведите код, библиотеку, версию библиотеки и php.

Comment: Как вариант - делайте replace для служебных `&amp;` `&quot;` и может некоторых других.

Comment: php Version : 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 ===
DOM/XML API Version : 20031129
libxml Version : 2.8.0

Comment: а как можно файл прикрепить? ибо код очень длинный

Comment: @teran функция `function trt_champ($parser,$data){
 global $depth,$branche, $prof_cour;
 global $debug;
 global $guide2BD;
 $jpk = "true";
 global $empty_tag;
 $empty_tag = "trt_champ";
 if(isset($guide2BD[$branche[$prof_cour]["nom"]]) and
  $guide2BD[$branche[$prof_cour]["nom"]]["type"] == "mark"){
  return 0;
 }` до нее $data содержит данные одной строкой, а после вызова xml_set_default_handler в trt_champ(..) они уже разбиты на три...